# Rename file in Node.js without using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, file-rename

Is there any way to rename file in Node js without using `fs` package. Since it says `Security holding package` in NPM Respository
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs.

Comment: `Since fs is deprecated` what do you mean?

Comment: `Since fs is deprecated or unable to use.`  `fs` is completely stable Err, what? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

Comment: It isn't deprecated. Use `rename` method: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Comment: [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) is Stable

Comment: You're making a confusion between native Nodejs `fs` module and a fs npm package name that is currently locked for security reasons.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification. I understood the point. Since I am new to Nodejs got into confusion between Nodejs `fs` and NPM package `fs`.

Answer (score 3):

`fs` module is not deprecated. Also, it has a `rename` method:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Comment: But if you see `fs` package it says `Security holding package`. So I din't want to use that, hence I asked for help. Anyways thanks for the suggestion, I had already used `fs.rename` method.

Comment: This one https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs is not the same as this one https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to use `fs`, you could rename your file with child_process `exec`:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('mv old_file_name new_file_name');
```